# How to use window.onload in angular js controller?

Tags: angularjs

How to use `window.onload` function inside a controller.

```
 window.onload= function() { 
    console.log("Hi Page loaded")
   };
```

The controller is not applicable for the full page. 
I want to execute a function after my controller loads at-least.

Comment: A controller is a function. Put code directly in that function, and it will be executed when the controller function is called by angular.

Comment: Angular functions will execute asynchronously. I want to run a particular function after all the other functions completes execution.

Comment: You really, really need to clarify your question. First you talk about window.onload. Then you say "after my controller loads". Then you say "after all the other functions completes execution", bu wothout saying what those other functions are. What are you trying to achieve, at a higher level? What would you like your controller to do?

Comment: `window.onload` will execute after page loads completely. So i wanted to use `window.onload` in my code. But my application is loading within another page. So the controller which i wrote is not for the full page. Thats why window.onload is not working. So alternate option i have is execute a function after all other function completes execution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use **[ng-init](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit)** and invoke your necessary function using the same directive

```js
var app = angular.module('DemoApp', [])
app.controller('akuaController', function($scope) {
  $scope.load = function() {
    alert("Window is loaded");
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.7" data-semver="1.4.7" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.7/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-filter/0.4.7/angular-filter.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="DemoApp" ng-controller="akuaController">
  <div ng-init="load()">
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This is not waiting for the DOM being entirely loaded.

Answer (score 1):

Changing the example from [Angular $window](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$window)

**Your Controller**

```
angular.module('windowExample', [])
    .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', '$window', function($scope, $window) {
      $scope.greeting = 'Hello, World!';
      $scope.doGreeting = function(greeting) {

        // This would be a starting point
        $window.onload(greeting);
      };
    }]);
```

**Your markup**

```
<div ng-controller="ExampleController" ng-init="ExampleController.doGreeting()">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
//inside your controller

$scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function() {

    // write here

    // either methods or variables 

});
```